# Request DTO populating order and validation

Tags: servicestack

Given
a route for .Add("/countries/{Id}", "PUT")
and the UpdateCountry DTO with a property named Id
When
a request for /countries/1 has been received
and a body as {"Id":0,...}
Then
the UpdateCountry dto instance forwarded to the service method

```
public object Any(UpdateCountry request)
```

has the Id property value of 1 (as per url segment request, not 0 as per body data)

How/Where can detect(and throw an exception) that inconsistent values supplied for the Id property (url segment vs body data)?

That behaviour make me wonder the url segment wins over body. Where I can found some documentation about DTO populate ordering(url segment/querystring/body)/criteria?

PS: I need to have the Id in the url segment and also within the dto itself due to soap compatibility, but I'd like to make sure who uses the rest endpoint does not send an inconsistent request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access different components of the HTTP Request in your Service with `base.Request`, e.g:

```
public object Any(UpdateCountry request)
{
    var queryStringId = base.Request.QueryString["id"];
    var formDataId = base.Request.FormData["id"];
    var pathInfo = base.Request.PathInfo; // /countries/1
}
```

The default request binding first deserializes the request DTO that's posted in the body then overrides it with any PathInfo, QueryString and FormData variables (if any). You can also override the default request binding behavior by [registering your own binding Strategy](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#create-a-custom-request-dto-binder).

Comment: Thanks @mythz, that makes perfectly sense. A custom binding seems the way to go in case I want do some AOP to keep my service "protocol/communication unaware"? I mean, I'd like to perform that check, only if the request comes from a rest endpoint, not everytime hits the service method.